# How can I use two different req items to create a new document in MongoDB?

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express, mongoose

In my application, I have `req.body` and `req.user`. I want to use both of these to create a new document. This is as far as I was able to get with my code. It seems like Model.create only takes one of these inputs, though. What's the best way to get both `createdBy` and the data contained within `req.body` to create the new document?

```
exports.createOne = Model =>
  catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
    const createdBy = req.user.id;
    const doc = await Model.create(req.body, createdBy);
    res.status(201).json({
      status: 'success',
      data: {
        data: doc
      }
    });
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

I forgot that req.body is just an object, so the easiest way to achieve what I was trying to do is simply:

```
req.body.createdBy = req.user.id
```